# subsetting, not selecting as intended

Tags: r, subset

Subsetting some data, key code line is

`newdata1 <- subset(mydata, key > 15, select = -c(unwanted columns) & class=='BIG')`

I want to generate a table, selecting only BIG, where a value elsewhere is > 15.

The code as written is ignoring key > 15, and giving me *all* the entries under client e.g. BIG, MEDIUM, SMALL.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
newdata1 %>%
   filter(key > 15 & class == "BIG") %>%
   select(-c(unwanted_columns))
```